# Using a relative (unknown) reference with formulaR1C1

Tags: excel, vba, string, reference

I'm trying to input a simple formula in the current active cell. The formula should include a rounding of a division of the cell to the left by the last cell with data on the same column (which is a total).

I'm using this:

```
Dim strAddress3 As String
strAddress3 = Range("G8").End(xlDown).Address
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+ROUND(RC[-1]/" & strAddress3 & ",2)"
```

Apparently, I can't use strAddress3 but I don't know why.

My apologies if this is a simple questions, I've been looking for an answer but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Address without further arguments returns the address in the xlA1 notation. I think you should use `strAddress3 = Range("G8").End(xlDown).Address(true, true, xlR1C1 )`